# percentage of nulls in a given line in a given table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i  need to create a scalar function that i will give it a table name and a row id and return me the percentage of nulls in that given row in the same table , any idea how to do that in sql server ,

the reason is to show to users how mush data they still need to insert .

EXEMPLE : TABLE STUDENT

```
ID_STUDENT | FNAME | LNAME | AGE | CITY
1 | KHALID |      SMITH |  25   |LA
2 |   ADAM |      NULL  |  NULL |NY
3 |   SARA |      KAMAL |   23  |Null
4 |   Null |       Null | Null  |Null

SELECT NULL_CALC(STUDENT,ID_STUDENT,1) ===> 0%
SELECT NULL_CALC(STUDENT,ID_STUDENT,2) ===> 50%
SELECT NULL_CALC(STUDENT,ID_STUDENT,3) ===> 25%
SELECT NULL_CALC(STUDENT,ID_STUDENT,4) ===> 100%
```

thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have dynamic sql inside user defined function. You have to write stored procedure. Below code will work for any table. But, I would suggest you to have proper error handling and other things to the below procedure.

**Data Setup**

```sql
CREATE TABLE studentPercentage(studentId int, Fname varchar(30), LName varchar(30),
Age tinyint, city varchar(30))

insert into studentPercentage 
values (1 ,'KHALID', 'SMITH' ,  25   ,'LA'),
(2 ,'ADAM',     NULL  , NULL ,'NY'),
(3 ,'SARA',      'KAMAL' ,   23  ,Null),
(4 ,Null,       Null , Null  ,Null);
```

**Procedure definition**

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.NULL_CALC
@tableName sysname,
@Idcolumn sysname,
@IdValue INT
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @percentagestmt VARCHAR(max) = 'SELECT ('
DECLARE @countOfColumns INT = (SELECT COUNT(c.name) FROM
sys.tables as t
inner join sys.columns as c
on c.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE t.name = @tableName)

SELECT @percentagestmt += 'CASE WHEN '+ c.name + ' IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +'
FROM sys.tables as t
inner join sys.columns as c
on c.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE t.name = @tableName

SET @percentagestmt = LEFT(@percentageStmt,LEN(@percentagestmt) -1)

SET @percentagestmt += ') * 100 /' + CAST(@countOfColumns AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' AS RowNullPercentage FROM ' + @tableName + ' WHERE ' + @Idcolumn + '=' + cast(@Idvalue as varchar(10))

EXEC(@percentagestmt)
END
```

**Procedure calling **

```sql
EXEC dbo.NULL_CALC 'StudentPercentage','StudentId',1
```

**Resultset**

```
+-------------------+
| RowNullPercentage |
+-------------------+
|               100 |
+-------------------+
```

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH IT'S JUST WHAT I NEEDED

Answer (score 3):

You could sum `CASE` expressions here to find the percentages:

```
SELECT
    ID_STUDENT,
    100.0 * (CASE WHEN FNAME IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
             CASE WHEN LNAME IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
             CASE WHEN AGE   IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
             CASE WHEN CITY  IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / 4 AS pct_null
FROM STUDENT;
```

[image: screen capture of demo link below]

### Demo

Comment: thank you ,but i need my function to be dynamic , meaning it will take any table and id i give it and it will return me the presentage

Comment: Then you may take the above query and modify it to use dynamic SQL.  You didn't mention this requirement in your question, hence I did not answer to that.